# Can't use eval-replace-last-sexp in multiple-cursors

Tags: multiple-cursors

In scratch file I has:

```
(* 60 10)
(* 50 100)
(* 50 200)
```

I want to use my custom function **replace-last-sexp**  (**C-c C-l**)

```
(defun replace-last-sexp ()
(interactive)
(let ((value (eval (preceding-sexp))))
  (kill-sexp -1)
  (insert (format "%S" value))))
```

To do this I use **multiple-cursors** package - https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el

After I press C-c C-l in **multiple-cursors** mode I get this:

```
600
(* 50 100)
(* 50 200)
```

[image]

Why not calculate another lines?

Comment: Where does `eval-replace-last-sexp` come from? I don't have it in my emacs. If I do `C-x C-e` (i.e. `eval-last-sexp`) all three expressions get evaluated (with the results in the echo area).

Comment: I found a [`replace-last-sexp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035574/2561714), bound it to `C-c r` and tried it: it asked me whether I wanted to apply it to all the cursors, I said "yes" and it worked. I have subsequently applied it again without having to answer any questions.

Comment: @NickD  replace-last-sexp not ask  me about apply to all cursors. Just replace first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue as you. And I'm not asked if I want to apply this function to other cursors ... strange, becuase I did expect this question. Maybe there are some changes in multiple-cursors recently?

I also can't answer your "why" question.

But here is some source code, to make it do, what you expect.

```
(defun replace-last-sexp--internal ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((value (eval (preceding-sexp))))
    (kill-sexp -1)
    (insert (format "%S" value))))

(defun replace-last-sexp ()
  (interactive)
  (if (functionp 'mc/execute-command-for-all-cursors)
      (mc/execute-command-for-all-cursors #'replace-last-sexp--internal)
    (replace-last-sexp--internal)))
```